# Partial derivative of a diagonal matrix w.r.t a vector

Tags: matrices, partial-derivative, matrix-calculus, tridiagonal-matrices

I am trying to find the second partial derivative of the function

$Y=diag\boldsymbol(S)\mathbb P diag \boldsymbol(\beta)diag^{-1}(\mathbb P^{T}\boldsymbol S +\mathbb P^{T}\boldsymbol E + \mathbb P^{T}\boldsymbol I +\mathbb P^{T}\boldsymbol R )\mathbb P^{T}\boldsymbol I$

where $\mathbb P=[(p_{ij})]_{n\times n},\boldsymbol S, \boldsymbol E, \boldsymbol I$ and $\boldsymbol R $ are $n\times 1$ vectors

with respect to $\boldsymbol S$. I am not sure of how to approach this. I was thinking of using the product rule whereby I will take
$$ X=\underbrace{diag\boldsymbol(S)\mathbb P diag \boldsymbol(\beta)}_{Y}\underbrace{diag^{-1}(\mathbb P^{T}\boldsymbol S +\mathbb P^{T}\boldsymbol E + \mathbb P^{T}\boldsymbol I +\mathbb P^{T}\boldsymbol R )\mathbb P^{T}\boldsymbol I}_{Z}$$ so that $$ \frac{\partial X}{\partial \boldsymbol S}=\frac{\partial Y}{\partial \boldsymbol S}Z+Y\frac{\partial Z}{\partial\boldsymbol S}$$

This is proving difficult to achieve as I am not sure if what I am thinking of doing is correct. For example, I was thinking of taking $D=diag(\mathbb P^{T}\boldsymbol S +\mathbb P^{T}\boldsymbol E + \mathbb P^{T}\boldsymbol I +\mathbb P^{T}\boldsymbol R )$ so that $$\frac{\partial Z}{\partial S}=-D\frac{\partial D}{\partial S}D^{-1}\mathbb P^{T}\boldsymbol I$$ where $$\frac{\partial D}{\partial S}=\mathbb P^{T}$$  Is this process correct? Because I am imagigning that this method (for the derivative of the inverse of a matrix) can only be applied when one is finding the derivative w.r.t a matrix and not w.r.t a vector. Could somebody help me obtain $\frac{\partial X}{\partial\boldsymbol S}$ and subsequently $\frac{\partial^{2} X}{\partial\boldsymbol S^{2}}$, $\frac{\partial^{2} X}{\partial\boldsymbol I\partial \boldsymbol E}$. I will appreciate it very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$
\def\e{\varepsilon}
\def\l{\left}
\def\r{\right}
\def\lr#1{\l(#1\r)}
\def\d#1{\operatorname{diag}\lr{#1}\,}
\def\D#1{\operatorname{Diag}\lr{#1}\,}
\def\v#1{\operatorname{vec}\lr{#1}\,}
\def\o{{\tt1}}
\def\p{{\partial}}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\hess#1#2#3{\frac{\p^2 #1}{\p #2\,\p #3^T}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\E{{\cal E}}
$Notation is going to be very important in answering this question. So first, let's use a convention in which uppercase letters denote matrices and lowercase letters vectors.

Let's further stipulate that an uppercase letter denotes the diagonal matrix generated by the corresponding lowercase vector, e.g.
$$\eqalign{
S = \D{s}, \quad E = \D{e}, \quad etc \\
}$$
We'll also reserve $I$ to denote the identity matrix.

So let's rename your variables as follows
$$({\mathbb P},\beta,S,E,I,R,X) \to (P,b,s,e,a,r,x)$$
and for typing convenience, introduce a new vector
$$w = P^T(s+e+a+r)\quad\implies\quad dw = P^Tds$$
The following commutativity relationship will be key
$$\D{a}b=\D{b}a$$
Write the function, then calculate the differential and thence the gradient
(with respect to $s$).
$$\eqalign{
x &= SPBW^{-1}P^Ta \\
dx &= dS\,PBW^{-1}P^Ta + SPB\,dW^{-1}P^Ta \\
   &= dS\,PBW^{-1}P^Ta + SPB\c{\lr{-W^{-2}dW}}P^Ta \\
   &= \D{ds}PBW^{-1}P^Ta - SPBW^{-2}\D{P^Tds}P^Ta \\
   &= \D{PBW^{-1}P^Ta}ds - SPBW^{-2}\D{P^Ta}P^Tds \\
\grad{x}{s}
   &= \D{PBW^{-1}P^Ta} - SPBW^{-2}\D{P^Ta}P^T \\
}$$
This is a matrix-valued gradient, so the higher order derivatives will be tensors. I'm not sure how you want to handle that.

There are lots of options. You can use tensors, or component-wise index notation, or use Kronecker products to flatten the matrix gradient into a long vector.
$$\\$$

---

**UPDATE**

The calculation of the gradient wrt $a$ is similar, and even a bit easier
$$\eqalign{
x &= SPBW^{-1}P^Ta \\
dx &= SPBW^{-1}P^Tda + SPB\,dW^{-1}P^Ta \\
   &= SPBW^{-1}P^Tda + SPB\c{\lr{-W^{-2}dW}}P^Ta \\
   &= SPBW^{-1}P^Tda - SPBW^{-2}\D{P^Tda}P^Ta \\
   &= SPBW^{-1}P^Tda - SPBW^{-2}\D{P^Ta}P^Tda \\
\grad{x}{a}
   &= SPBW^{-1}P^T - SPBW^{-2}\D{P^Ta}P^T \\
}$$
Now calculate the differential of $\,G=\lr{\grad{x}{a}}\,$
with respect to $e$ as the first step in the cross-hessian
$$\eqalign{
dG &= SPB\,\c{ \lr{dW^{-1}}  }\,P^T - SPB\,\D{P^Ta}\c{ \lr{dW^{-2}} }P^T \\
  &= SPB\,\c{ \lr{-W^{-2}dW} }\,P^T - SPB\,\D{P^Ta}\c{ \lr{-2\,W^{-3}dW} }P^T \\
  &= 2\,SPB\,\D{P^Ta}W^{-3}\,\D{P^Tde}\,P^T - SPBW^{-2}\,\D{P^Tde}\,P^T \\
}$$
At this point we need the vectorization function
$(\v{G}\!)$
the Khatri-Rao product $(\boxtimes)$ defined in term of all-ones vectors $(\o)$ and the Kronecker $(\otimes)$ and Hadamard $(\odot)$ products, plus the obscure $\c{\rm relationship}$
$$\eqalign{
&\c{ {\rm vec}(F\,\D{g}\,H) = \left(H^T\boxtimes F\right)g } \\
&H^T\boxtimes F = (H^T\otimes{\o_m})\odot({\o_p}\otimes F)
  \;\in {\mathbb R}^{(mp)\times n} \\
&F \in {\mathbb R}^{m\times n},\quad 
g \in {\mathbb R}^{n},\quad 
H \in {\mathbb R}^{n\times p},\quad
\o_m \in {\mathbb R}^{m} \\
}$$
This yields
$$\eqalign{
dg &= \bigg(
P\boxtimes\Big( 2\,SPB\,\D{P^Ta}W^{-3} - SPBW^{-2} \Big)
\bigg)\,P^T\,de \\
\grad{g}{e} &= \bigg(
P\boxtimes\Big( 2\,SPB\,\D{P^Ta}W^{-3} - SPBW^{-2} \Big)
\bigg)\,P^T \\
}$$
So that's the vectorized version of $\lr{\hess{x}{e}{a}}$

At this point my questions are:

 $\;$ Why do you need complicated tensor quantities like these?

 $\;$ What will they be used for?

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answer is very useful to me. I love it. At least that is several steps towards the final end. Your last comment about higher order derivatives being tensors takes me to unknown waters. I guess I will have to search more on how that is done. Thank you very much for your time and input :)

Comment: Kindly allow me to come back to you. I have been struggling to understand how I can use the tensors or vectorization approach to continue your solution above to obtain the second order derivative but I am sadly not able to understand :( I have tried to use your procedure to, for example, obtain the second derivative w.r.t a and e but I get some equation where I am not able to explicitly factor out `de`. I am kindly asking if you are able to give more insights about this. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you very much @greg for the continuation. I honestly admit that I would not be able to figure out how to combine the vectorization, the Khatri-Rao product (I didn't even know that this product exits), the Kronecker and the Hadamand products. I actually got stuck in the exact previous step. This is some dense knowledge in matrix calculus. Thumbs up. To answer your questions, I need these second order derivatives for purposes of doing bifurcation analysis of some patchy epidemic model. The model is indeed complex, but thanks to you for helping me deconstruct this derivative part.

Comment: A quick follow-up on this @greg. What if I change the above equation so that your `w` becomes `w=P(s+e+a+r)^{T}`? I believe that will not change the workings, right?

Comment: The dimensions don't work. If you want to transpose the column vectors to create row vectors, then you must move them from the RHS to the LHS of the matrix, i.e.  $w^T=(s+e+a+r)^TP^T\quad$

Comment: Okay @greg. Makes sense. I was actually going through the workings and I realized that I erred in writing `w`. Instead of ``w=P^{T}(s+e+a+r)``, it should be ``w=(s+e+a+r)^{T}P``. I have however checked and seen that whereas ``w=P^{T}(s+e+a+r)`` is a column vector, ``w=(s+e+a+r)^{T}P`` is a row vector with the same entries.  Hence the `Diag` function returns the same diagonal matrix for both formulations. I therefore believe that the equivalence of the `Diag` function in both cases makes the workings with ``w=P^{T}(s+e+a+r)`` stand. Do you agree?

Comment: @AkunwexOrwa Yes, except you should be consistent with notation or you will shoot yourself in the foot at some inconvenient (or embarrassing) moment. For me, column vectors are the default, so I'd *always* write the row vector as $w^T$ never as $w\;$

Comment: thanks for your feedback. I perfectly understand your point :)